# Getting -NaN during DARKNET training, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nan, yolo, darknet

**I want to train YOLOv3 to detect humans on aerial pictures.** Im using VisDrone Object Detection in Images dataset:
[github.com/VisDrone/VisDrone-Dataset](https://github.com/VisDrone/VisDrone-Dataset)

I wrote a script that converted labels to darknet format so that i can train it according to pjreddie "Training YOLO on COCO" instructions, I double checked if my converted labels match the objects correctly and they do, I also created a proper coco.names file according to labels description on VisDrone2018-DET-toolkit on github.  I created trainvalno5k.txt file by running

python 5kGenerator.py > trainvalno5k.txt

5kGenerator.py:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    print( os.path.abspath( os.path.join( 'images', filename )))
```

I modified coco.data file, this is the result:

```
classes= 12
train  = /mnt/d/Olaf/Documents/Python/VisDrone2019-DET-train/trainvalno5k.txt
#valid  = /mnt/d/Olaf/Documents/Python/VisDrone2019-DET-train/5k.txt
#valid = data/coco_val_5k.list
names  = /mnt/d/Olaf/Documents/Python/VisDrone2019-DET-train/coco.names
backup = backup
#eval=coco
```

I commented valid out because as far as I understand its for checking results and valid dataset is irrelevant for training (I didn't bother to create it).

When I run ./darknet detector train cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg darknet53.conv.74 stuff loads correctly and **training starts, but every few lines i get -nan messages and I have no idea why** and if that has impact on the end result, example:

```
Loading weights from darknet53.conv.74...Done!
Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.0005
Resizing
416
Loaded: 1.122782 seconds
Region 82 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.428162, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 94 Avg IOU: 0.409795, Class: 0.690346, Obj: 0.091164, No Obj: 0.519810, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 1
Region 106 Avg IOU: 0.157575, Class: 0.532119, Obj: 0.333807, No Obj: 0.417611, .5R: 0.045685, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 197
Region 82 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.427261, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
```

Its pretty slow because im testing this on CPU, proper training will be done on Nvidia Quadro

**Can you please explain this behaviour and what can i do to fix that -nan problem?**

*Ps. Im using Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10, I dont know if thats important.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's better to using [AlexeyAB repository](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) for training.
2. You should use Validation set or test for evaluation of trained networks on your data.
3. I have trained a 26 classes dataset and I ignored 5k classes & you have 12 classes.
4. for `Nan` value it's better to decrease Learning Rate in starting of training. and then increasing it.
5. you could train your network in windows & Linux and it's not matter.

Comment: So I understand that having -nan sometimes is ok?

Comment: @Leprawel Definitely it's not ok. you should resolve it. Sometimes by increasing Learning Rate, loss value reach to Nan or -Nan. You should check process of training again. Maybe you have a little problem in learning process and you ignored it.

Comment: you are right! i increased learning rate and -nan dissapeared

Comment: by the way, do you know if i can read full description of yolov3.cfg somewhere? i dont know what some stuff there means

Comment: @Leprawel you could read main article or read some medium articles. I suggest medium.com .

Comment: https://medium.com/@amrokamal_47691/yolo-yolov2-and-yolov3-all-you-want-to-know-7e3e92dc4899            https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088     https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/yolo-v3-theory-explained-33100f6d193    https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-v3-object-detection-53fb7d3bfe6b    https://towardsdatascience.com/review-yolov3-you-only-look-once-object-detection-eab75d7a1ba6    http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1354883/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: @Leprawel By using AlexeyAB repository, you could check over-fitting, affect of Learning Rate, best weight & so on.

Comment: thanks for all the help guys, really appreciate it :)